# Two different answers with different methods in solving limits.

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

So the question is,
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\{\frac{(1+x){\log(1+x)} - x}{x^2}\}$$

Method 1:
Applying l'hopital's rule the limit tend to $\bigl(\frac{1}{2}\bigr)$.

Method 2:
Solving the following way:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \biggl(\frac{(1+x)\log(1+x)}{x^2}\biggr)-\lim_{x\to 0} \biggl(\frac{1}{x}\biggr)$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \biggl(\frac{1+x}{x}\biggr)\biggl(\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}\biggr)-\lim_{x\to 0} \biggl(\frac{1}{x}\biggr)$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \biggl(\frac{1}{x} + 1\biggr)\biggl(\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}\biggr)-\lim_{x\to 0} \biggl(\frac{1}{x}\biggr)$$
using property:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \Biggl(\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}\Biggr) = 1$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \biggl(\frac{1}{x} + 1\biggr)-\lim_{x\to 0} \biggl(\frac{1}{x}\biggr)$$ 
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \biggl(\frac{1}{x} + 1-\frac{1}{x}\biggr)$$ 
$$ = 1$$
So, why is the limit different for different methods ?

Comment: the answer using l'hopital's rule is actually $1/2$

Comment: Also, whatever else is at issue in method 2, be careful when you split a limit in 2, if doing so results in terms with $\infty$: for instance, it is clear $\lim_{x\to 0^+}{1\over x} = \infty$. Less clear, but $\lim_{x\to 0^+} {(1 +x )\log( 1 + x)\over x^2} =\infty$, also. So you have [sort of] written down "$\infty -\infty$," which is meaningless as it stands. (On the other hand, "$4-\infty$" is meaningful.)

Comment: @peterag                                                                                                                                                         "$\infty - \infty$" is not meaningless if they are from the same function, in this case, $\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: @RupanshuYadav - $\infty - \infty$ is meaningless on its own. $\lim_{x\to0} \frac1x - \lim_{x\to0} \frac1x$ is not defined, it is not zero.

Comment: @RupanshuYadav : It is important, conceptually speaking,  to bear in mind that a limit, if it exists, is a number ($+\infty$ and $-\infty$ are numbers for this discussion). Now, a number does not 'remember' how it was calculated. Therefore, in calculus, one should think "$\infty - \infty = \cdots$" doesn't scan... It's almost a question of grammar, rather semantics. You cannot recombine the difference into a single expression (the $\cdots$ on the RHS of the $=$) - you're not 'allowed' to know where the $\infty$ came from, once you wrote it down. I hope this is clear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, you cannot expand out the limit as you have done and then recombine, when the parts tend to infinity.

To see what I mean, consider the following reversed example...

$$\begin{align}
1 = \lim_{x\to0} \frac{x}x &= \lim_{x\to0} \frac{x+1}x - \lim_{x\to0} \frac1x\\
&\neq\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x+1}x(1-x) - \lim_{x\to0} \frac1x\\
&= \lim_{x\to0} \frac{1-x^2}x - \lim_{x\to0} \frac1x\\
&= \lim_{x\to0} \frac{1-x^2 - 1}x\\
&= \lim_{x\to0} \frac{-x^2}x = 0
\end{align}$$

By looking at the step with the $\neq$, we can see what is going on, here...
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x+1}x(1-x) = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x+1}x - \lim_{x\to 0}\ (x+1)
$$
And so, multiplying $\frac{x+1}x$ by $1-x$, which has a limit of 1, has the effect of subtracting $\lim_{x\to 0} (x+1) = 1$ from the limit, thus changing the result.

The same applies here, albeit in a less obvious form. In particular, notice that
$$
\frac{\log(1+x)}x \approx 1\color{red}{-\frac{x}2}+O(x^2)
$$
If you examine what happens if you add this extra term (in red) to your expression, you end up with the right result.

---

On a more general note, splitting limits only works if the limits of the parts exist. This applies to both addition and multiplication splitting. For example,
$$
\lim_{x\to0} \left(\frac1x-\frac1x\right) \neq \lim_{x\to 0} \frac1x - \lim_{x\to 0} \frac1x
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac1xx\right) \neq \lim_{x\to 0} \frac1x \times \lim_{x\to 0} x
$$

Comment: @peterag - Oops, sorry about that. Fixed.