# Confusion in this algebraic limit approaching infinity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

> **Question** : Evaluate $\lim_{x \to \infty}{\frac{1}{1+x^2} + \frac{2}{2+x^2} + \frac{3}{3+x^2}+...+\frac{x}{x + x^2}}$.

My working:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}{\frac{1}{1+x^2} + \frac{2}{2+x^2} + \frac{3}{3+x^2}+...+\frac{x}{x + x^2}}$$
Dividing and transforming each fraction by $x^2$in the numerator and denominator.
$$=\lim_{x \to \infty}{\frac{\frac{1}{x^2}}{\frac{1}{x^2} +1} +...+\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{1}{x} + 1}}$$
Using algebra of limits we get,
$$0+0+...+0 = 0$$

But when solving this using **Sandwich Theorem** I get,

$$\text{Let }\lim_{x \to \infty}{\frac{1}{1+x^2} + \frac{2}{2+x^2} + \frac{3}{3+x^2}+...+\frac{x}{x + x^2}} = g(x)$$
$$g(x) < \frac{1}{1+x^2} + \frac{2}{2 + x^2}+...+\frac{x}{1+x^2}$$
$$g(x) < \frac{x(x+1)}{2(1 + x^2)}$$
$$g(x) > \frac{1}{x+x^2} + \frac{2}{x+x^2} +...+\frac{x}{x+x^2}$$
$$g(x) > \frac{x(x+1)}{2(x+x^2)} \to g(x) > \frac{1}{2} $$
$$\text{So, we get } \frac{1}{2}<g(x)<\frac{x(x+1)}{2(1 + x^2)}$$
Applying limits,
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}{\frac{x^2+x}{2(1+x^2)}} = 1/2$$
$$\text{Finally, we get } \frac{1}{2}<g(x)<\frac{1}{2}$$
By Sandwich theorem, $\lim_{x \to \infty}{\frac{1}{1+x^2} + \frac{2}{2+x^2} + \frac{3}{3+x^2}+...+\frac{x}{x + x^2}} =\frac{1}{2}$

**So, my question is Why am I getting two different answers when worked out differently.**
*If there is any error or misconception in my working, please correct me.*

Comment: can't use algebra of limits for infinitely many terms

Comment: May I know why I can't use it for infinite terms? @J.W.Tanner

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/92989/444015 maybe it will be useful.

Comment: $\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^N \frac 1 N = \lim_{N \to \infty} 1 = 1$ but your argument would be analogous to saying this is $0$

Comment: Your first argument is analogous to saying that $1/n+\cdots+1/n$ (with $n$ terms) tends to zero as $n\to\infty$ as $1/n\to0$ etc.

Comment: The number of terms in your sum depends on $x$, so you can't take the limit for each term separately. Like mentioned in the previous comment, consider $f(x)=\sum_1^x 1/x$. Obviously $f(x)=1$ so its limit as $x\to\infty$ is $1$, but if you were to take the limit if each term, you would find that the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be totally wrong but looking at the top formula, it seems that you are rather considering 
$$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac i{i+n^2}=n \left(n H_{n^2}-n H_{n^2+n}+1\right)$$ where appear harmonic numbers.

Using the asymptotics
$$H_p=\gamma +\log \left({p}\right)+\frac{1}{2 p}-\frac{1}{12
   p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^4}\right)$$ Replacing and continuing with Taylor expansions for large value of $n$, you get
$$S_n=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6 n}-\frac{1}{4 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

[Two different answers with different methods in solving limits.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3101282/two-different-answers-with-different-methods-in-solving-limits)

here you know the two important things are there one is $x\rightarrow\infty$ and and also the terms are variying as 1,2,3.....
you mean by individualy taking them as constant even when they are going to $\infty$
for example this below
[similar misleading question by your point of view](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1179337/evaluating-lim-n-to-infty-frac1n-left-fracnn1-fracnn2?rq=1)
here also the sum might tend to something different.
but the $k$ as a variable makes difference.